# C# using regex to replace value only after = sign

Tags: c#, regex

ok I have a text file that contains:

```
    books_book1 = 1
    books_book2 = 2
    books_book3 = 3
```

I would like to retain "books_book1 = "

so far I have:

```
string text = File.ReadAllText("settings.txt");
text = Regex.Replace(text, ".*books_book1*.", "books_book1 = a",
RegexOptions.Multiline);
File.WriteAllText("settings.txt", text);
text = Regex.Replace(text, ".*books_book2*.", "books_book2 = b",
RegexOptions.Multiline);
File.WriteAllText("settings.txt", text);
text = Regex.Replace(text, ".*books_book3*.", "books_book3 = c",
RegexOptions.Multiline);
File.WriteAllText("settings.txt", text);
```

this results in:

> books_book1 = a=1

output to file should be:

```
    books_book1 = a
    books_book2 = b
    books_book3 = c
```

Thanks much in advance...

Comment: `.*` matches any number of characters, except newline. `*` matches the *preceding* character any number of times. `.` matches any character except newline.

Comment: whats the question exactly?

Comment: You don't really need `Regex`, do you? You can do it using `string.Replace()`..

Comment: Something odd here. If you only have those three lines then why use regex or the input file? Why not just create a new file with the three new lines? I guess it's not that simple...maybe you have `books_book` followed by a number but not necessarily 1, 2 and 3?

Comment: exactly its random it could be 4 5 or 6

Comment: I want to get rid of =1 at the end so it's only = a

Comment: And you have to replace 1 by a, 2 by b, 3 by c, etc?

Comment: when the program loads it reads the values from this text file, then the user has an option to change the values and save it back to the file, so next time the program starts, it's using the new values. That's all I'm trying to accomplish ;) tnx

Comment: Then the replacements are not fixed to `a` `b` or `c` as you indicated. Please provide us with some more code on how the user changes those values.

Comment: I would personally just go for recreating the file if it is that simple. Presumably you load all the values from the file into an object of some kind initially so just use that to recreate the file with the new values. Much easier than messing with Regularexpressions - its simpler and easier to test and see what is going on and easier to change if you ever need to.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is the best way to solve the problem, but to make the RegEx do what you want you can do the following:

```
var findFilter = @"(.*books_book1\s*=\s)(.+)";
var replaceFilter = "${1}a"    
text = Regex.Replace(text, findFilter, replaceFilter, RegexOptions.Multiline)   
File.WriteLine("settings.txt", text);
....
```

The code between the `(` and `)` in the regex is in this case the first and only back reference capturing group and `${1}` in the replace portion will use the matching group text to create the output you want. Also you'll notice I used `\s` for white space so you don't match book111 for example. I'm sure there are other edge cases you'll need to deal with.

```
books_book1 = a
...
```

Comment: I replaced the .*1" with .*" because it's not always going to be 1

Comment: There are some probably mistakes in the regex too that should probably be addressed or at least noted. eg `books_book1*` probably isn't intended to match `books_book111` or indeed `books_book`...

Comment: how do I add a new line at the end because I'm getting books_book1 = abooks_book2 = b on one line..

Comment: @Chris Updated for the `books_book111` problem. I was just trying to show though what I thought the crux of his problem was, in that he wasn't using grouping/back references.

Comment: @Matt: Yup. I should note briefly that I wasn't the -1. However I made the comment because although your answer may be right (regex are one of those things that I am often nervous about +1ing without testing) I could see that it could be improved.

Comment: A couple more notes (I could edit them in myself but prefer to let the original answerer do so). Regex.Replace doesn't change the original string, it returns a new one so that would need to be assigned to something. A couple of missing semi-colons (they are just typos, I know).

Comment: hmm I get "unrecognized espace sequience on this line: var findFilter = "(.*books_book1\s*=\s)(.+)";

Answer (score 2):

In a comment I stated:

"I would personally just go for recreating the file if it is that simple. Presumably you load all the values from the file into an object of some kind initially so just use that to recreate the file with the new values. Much easier than messing with Regularexpressions - its simpler and easier to test and see what is going on and easier to change if you ever need to."

I think having looked at this again it is even more true.

From what you said in comments: "when the program loads it reads the values from this text file, then the user has an option to change the values and save it back to the file". Presumably this means that you need to actually know which of the books1, books2, etc. lines you are replacing so you know which of the user supplied values to put in. This is fine (though a little unwieldy) with three items but if you increase that number then you'll need to update your code for every new item. This is never a good thing and will quickly produce some very horrendous looking code liable to get bugs in.

If you have your new settings in some kind of data structure (eg a dictionary) then as I say recreating the file from scratch is probably easiest. See for example this small fully contained code snippet:

```
//Set up our sample Dictionary
Dictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string,string>();
settings.Add("books_book1","a");
settings.Add("books_book2","b");
settings.Add("books_book3","c");

//Write the values to file via an intermediate stringbuilder.    
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (var item in settings)
{
    sb.AppendLine(String.Format("{0} = {1}", item.Key, item.Value));
}

File.WriteAllText("settings.txt", sb.ToString());
```

This has obvious advantages of being simpler and that if you add more settings then they will just go into the dictionary and you don't need to change the code.

Comment: such a neat and direct approach, I love it! Thanks for your help Chris!   (I would vote up, but don't have the reputation yet)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the start to a more generic approach:

This regular expression captures the last digit, taking care to account for variability in digit and whitespace length.

```
text = Regex.Replace(text , @"(books_book\d+\s*=\s*)(\d+)", DoReplace)

// ... 

string DoReplace(Match m)
{
    return m.Groups[1].Value + Convert.ToChar(int.Parse(m.Groups[2].Value) + 96);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this (no error checking):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace TestRegex
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main( string[] args )
        {
            var path = @"settings.txt";
            var pattern = @"(^\s*books_book\d+\s*=\s*)(\d+)(\s*)$";
            var options = RegexOptions.IgnoreCase | RegexOptions.Multiline;
            var contents = Regex.Replace( File.ReadAllText( path ), pattern, MyMatchEvaluator, options );
            File.WriteAllText( path, contents );
        }

        static int x = char.ConvertToUtf32( "a", 0 );

        static string MyMatchEvaluator( Match m )
        {
            var x1 = m.Groups[ 1 ].Value;
            var x2 = char.ConvertFromUtf32( x++ );
            var x3 = m.Groups[ 3 ].Value;
            var result = x1 + x2 + x3;
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```